# Setting text beneath 2 side by side divs

Tags: html, css

What do I have to do in order to set the text underneath 2 divs that are displaying side by side (set by 'float: left'). Right now the text from the 'underneath' div is displaying to the right of the second div tag.

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 500px;   
}
#leftcolumn, #rightcolumn {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
}
#leftcolumn {
    background-color: #111;
}
#rightcolumn {
    background-color: #777;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftcolumn"></div>
    <div id="rightcolumn"></div>  
</div>
<div id="underneath">
    This should be underneath
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#underneath {
    clear: left;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/WPNgL/

Comment: It's best to add the code into the answer, as external links may not always be around and may eventually disappear.

Comment: @Metalskin: he indeed added the code, i dont get what you are asking for

Comment: @SajadLfc My mistake, I initially thought that the JSFiddle was required to understand the answer as I misread the question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#underneath{

   clear:both;
}
```

Here since you have used `float:left`, the `#underneath` div occupies the space at the left,
what you can do is that use `clear:left` or `clear:both` so that it appears below the other containers,even though there is space at left/right while using `clear:both`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8aL8e/)

FROM http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

> The `clear` property specifies which sides of an element where other
>   floating elements are not allowed.

```
 left  -->  No floating elements allowed on the left side 
 right -->  No floating elements allowed on the right side
 both  -->  No floating elements allowed on either the left or the right side
 none  -->  Default. Allows floating elements on both sides 
 inherit --> Specifies that the value of the clear property should be inherited from the parent  element
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="leftcolumn"></div>
   <div id="rightcolumn"></div>  
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
   <div id="underneath">
     This should be underneath
</div>
```

You have not cleared the float

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add a div to clear the float value

```
     .clear{
        clear:both;
      }
```

[Check on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsharma2r/YGw3V/)